# Ubuntu Gnome freezes

Tags: gnome, freeze

I am running the Ubuntu 14.10 with Gnome desktop. My machine is Lenovo t440s.

Specs: 
Processor: 4th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-4600U (4MB Cache, up to 3.30GHz)
12 GB RAM
GPU: Intel® HD Graphics 4400

The issue is that my desktop will freeze. This happens randomly and will occur if I do something such as pressing a button or even pressing ctrl-shift-t for new tab once.

I am not sure if this is an issue with Gnome shell or the kernel.

This doesn't happen frequently, probably once every 4 hours. Its not really predictable.

Once it does freeze, I can move my mouse smoothly. The cursor will change into I shape if it hovers over text. However, I cannot click anywhere. I tried to ctrl-alt-f1 to switch to terminal, but that does not work. So I am forced to hold the power button to reboot.

I will provide more details if needed. Is there any way I can keep a resource log so that once it happens, I can see exactly which process is responsible?

Any suggestions on the source of the problem or a fix is welcome.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes. Wait a bit, do the magic-sysrq thing, and hope that something is saved in the logs (/var/log/messages). Seems a panic. Do you have a wireless wacom tablet connect, by chance?

Comment: @Rmano Nope. However, I updated my kernel from 3.16.0 to 3.16.3 and so far it seems to be working fine right now. I'll give updates.

Answer (score 0):

DDR2  memory  clock  fixed at 200MHz  in  motherboard firmware **BiOS  CMOS setting**  solved my  *Random Screen Garble Freeze* bug related to  NViDiA graphics processor driver,  without any graphics driver update :)

DDR2 memory clock = "**Auto**"    =  old  default
  DDR2 memory clock = "**200MHz**"  =  new  fix

motherboard = ASUS  =  M2N MX SE PLUS;
BiOS = version 602 AMi BiOS  from  ASUS;
NViDiA graphics chip  =  GeForce6150SE;
DDR2 = 4GB( 2GB+2GB ) Transcend

"Auto" setting  in BiOS CMOS was defaulting to 400MHz DDR2 memory clock which used to randomly freeze & garble my display screen;

i  gave up NViDiA driver update as it had 
many other issues like  missing 1366x768 pixel option;

i used  Ubuntu built-in  xrandr  &  cvt  for  1366x768 pixel screen setup,  instead of using NViDiA graphics driver update ( just added the below 2 lines at the beginning of      ***/etc/gdm/Init/Default***   text file:;

```
xrandr --newmode 1366 85.25 1368 1440 1576 1784 768 771 781 798

xrandr --addmode VGA-1 1366
```

i don't need  NViDiA graphics driver update  anymore